# What is the sorting order on NULL values in oracle

Tags: oracle

Suppose a column many null values when I am applying sort on that column, then the rows containing the null values are getting sorted in the same way every time.

```
select * from departments order by manager_id
```

Comment: Is there a sorting order that applies on NULL values as well otherwise why is the output same every time

Comment: what you want ? null first?

Comment: Then specify a second column in your order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the order on the NULL values is not guaranteed. You can only specify whether or not the NULL values show up first or last.

`ORDER BY manager_id NULLS FIRST`

OR

`ORDER BY manager_id NULLS LAST`

If you need to specify an order to the nulls you could just add another column to the `ORDER BY`

Comment: `NULLS LAST` is the default for ascending (which itself is the default ordering sequence) order, and `NULLS FIRST` is the default for descending order., see [order_by_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079)

Comment: Right, but I believe he is referring to the order of the group of nulls which isn't guaranteed. The order within the order so to speak.

Comment: Yes I know nulls first for descending nulls last for ascending but rows containing null are ordered in the same order whether nulls first or nulls last. @SQLChao

Comment: @PrabhatBhatt That's what I was saying in my answer. The order of the NULLS is not going to be guaranteed unless you specify an additional column.